# Unique constraint violated even though the table is empty

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, unique-constraint

The `item_type` table is empty, yet on this:

```
INSERT INTO item_type (id, name) VALUES (1, 'PHYSICAL')
```

I get error:

```
Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (MYDB.SYS_C0013475) violated

SQLState:  23000
ErrorCode: 1
```

It seems like it's simply a PK constraint on `ITEM_TYPE` table, though I can't say for sure as I'm Oracle newbie.

But if it is, why does it prevent inserting into an empty table?

Note: I have been purging all database objects frequently to port the data again (due to administrative rights I cannot delete this db and recreate it).

**UPDATE**

SquirrelSQL apparently lies about table DDL, this is DDL I got via SQL query to Oracle:

```
  CREATE TABLE "MYDB"."ITEM_TYPE" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" NVARCHAR2(2000), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DATA"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DATA"
```

**It's been generated by SQLAlchemy (Python ORM) from class declaration.** This has worked without a hitch on PostgreSQL, yet on Oracle it gives me this kind of problem.

Comment: Not sure how you got a table to be created using that datatype definition. For DECIMAL (and NUMBER) the precision should be between 1 and 38 so I would expect you to get an ORA-01727 when you tried to create the table. Just taking generated code (even this code) at face value is risky; you need to understand it as well. Its not an answer but I suggest you look at the definitions and what the data is and make an Oracle-specific script. Towards the end of this page is a section on converting to Oracle datatypes - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm.

Comment: You probably need to look at the definition of constraint via all_constraints.  Also make sure there are no uncommitted transactions in your session, which make also cause PK violations during such testing.

Comment: This is what comes from not **explicitly** naming constraints. If the name was something meaningful instead of MYDB.SYS_C0013475, you might stand some chance of being able to find out what it is!

Comment: While I agree with explicitly naming constraints, they don't really add any value other than readability. You can always prefix a PK as FK and FK as PK causing more confusion. Looking up catalog views is only your true source.

Comment: is there another schema with an `ITEM_TYPE` table, and possibly a public synonym for it? Could be that you're not inserting into the table you think you're inserting into...